# Custom Indexer, TYPE_MASS_ACTION and TYPE_DELETE

Tags: magento-1.9, module, indexer

I am building a custom indexer and quick search based on a mysql table with fulltext indices and having some difficulties in understanding the `Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_DELETE` in conjunction with `TYPE_MASS_ACTION`.

The Indexer is build very similar to `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat`.

A single delete event is working just fine, the ID got passed with the data object and I can get it with `getId()` to proceed the deletion. But when I go to the Backend `Catalog -> Manage Products` List and mark a few products (via checkbox) for deletion and select the delete action, just one product ID out of the selected set will get deleted, the others remain in my index (via `Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_DELETE`). I supposed that the deletion of multiple products would be of `TYPE_MASS_ACTION`, just as it is for status change of products, but it seems not.

What event type gets triggered with multiple products deletion? Even though I would expect to get these to be deleted product IDs with `$product = $event->getDataObject();` and `$product->getProductIds()`. Or is there another way to solve this?

If been digging in Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php, the models and resources and can not find out how it is done.

Been sitting over this a few hours now, I might oversee it. Maybe somebody could shed some light on that question.

Any help and hints are appreciated!

Comment: This is just an idea. You should put a FK on your index table on the product id column to the `catalog_product_entity.entity_id` field with `ON DELETE CASCADE`. This way you don't have to worry about the delete event or the multiple delete event. Everything will cascade nicely.

Comment: @Marius: The table has MyISAM storage type and does not support foreign keys. Have to choose MyISAM, as only Mysql 5.6 InnoDB would support fulltext index.

Comment: OK. Got it. It was worth a shot. For the flat catalog tables this is how it's done. with FK and cascade.

Comment: @Marius: I already got a bad feeling when you gave your first comment with the FK cascade delete ... :-) OK, at least that explains now how it works. Thx! Seems not to be a simple task then ... sigh! Probably a mysql trigger can help ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give an answer to my own question:

I tried to emulate Marius suggestion with the `on delete cascade` by using the `on delete` trigger. But that trigger is not activated due to a remaining bug in MySQL that is ... "Currently, cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers".

So to overcome that I simply synchronize my fulltext index table with an SQL query by getting all product IDs that are not found in the Magento product index and delete them. In fact that the `Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_DELETE` is sent out this solution works pretty well.